# server does not lookup on www or other subdomains

Tags: apache, dns, server, subdomain, cpanel

I have some problems, and I think that it's for DNS Records.

I can't open my website by `www.` or access any sub-domain.

These are my DNS settings:

```
 example.de.        14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***  
 mail.example.de.   14400   IN  CNAME   example.de  
 www.example.de.    14400   IN  CNAME   example.de  
 ftp.example.de.    14400   IN  CNAME   example.de  
 *.example.de.      14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***   
 ns1.example.de.    14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***  
 ns2.example.de.    14400   IN  A   **.***.***.***
```

And when I do DNS lookup, I get the following:

```
Type    Host        Class   TTL     Data
A       example.de  IN      21599   ip = **.***.***.***
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.earth.orderbox-dns.com
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.mars.orderbox-dns.com
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.mercury.orderbox-dns.com
NS      example.de  IN      21599   target = irdns.venus.orderbox-dns.com
SOA     example.de  IN      7199    mname = irdns.mercury.orderbox-dns.com
                                    rname = example.mail.com
                                    serial = 2015081203
                                    refresh = 7200
                                    retry = 7200
                                    expire = 172800
                                    minimum-ttl = 38400
```

**`**.***.***.***`** is my server IP.

The problem is just on `.de`; I have set these settings to my other domain, and anything is fine.

My server is Apache, and it has default Apache Control Panel (CPanel) for management.

Comment: The TTLs that you say are configured do not line up with the TTLs that you get when testing. This would indicate that you're not looking at the right DNS server for that domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to have 2 `A` records for `example.de` pointing to different IP addresses

look your domain DNS setting or ask your domain hosting support

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

did you try applying same dns settings for www.yoururl.com as you did for yoururl.com

www.yoururl.com acts like a subdomain for you. from my learnings

Comment: your domain is hosted on which service?